# Embedding styles in plain text before inserting into Word

Tags: vba, ms-word

Can I apply a style markup to plain text before I insert it into Word?  Something like this?

```
<style = "normal">Line 1 of text
<style = "abc">Line 2 of text
<style = "normal">Line 3 of text
```

Then paste the whole thing.
Or do I have to

```
apply normal style, insert line 1
apply abc style, insert line 2 
apply normal style, insert line 3
```

Hope this makes sense. Thanks

Comment: For practical purposes, your second workflow is correct. You could take plain text and mark it up with html/xml markup, then use a VBA macro to decipher that, but that's a lot of time spent to save a few seconds. I usually just paste all the text, then run through the document applying styles.

Comment: «I usually just paste all the text, then run through the document applying styles» Ditto. For a simple demonstration, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66134669/vba-styling-paragraphs-in-word/66135021